# Spring boot, spring session, JDBC

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-session

My project is an attendance application which use Mobil app as UI to send user attendance, I have developed in spring boot, MySQL for DB, spring security. After login to application the user will have toggle button to say he/she is “IN” and the user can logout but I want start a new session when user say they are IN apart from login and logout, the user has to login app again and can say OUT by toggle button. How can I set or create a custom session for IN and OUT. This session should be active even when the user is logs out of application.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but if your are familiar with Spring Boot and Spring Security, look into those to see how to best set up sessions. This is always more secure that implementing your own solutions.